# Is there a way to pass a parameter to the button event function?

Tags: events, parameters, wxpython, parameter-passing

Is there a way to pass a parameter to the event function?  When I press the submit button, I receive the following error:

NameError: global name 'filename' is not defined

Here is the full error:

raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sbing\OneDrive\Documents\CNM\Spring2018\CIS1250_Python\Labs\Prgm11\geopoint.py", line 60, in submit
    file = open(filename.GetValue(), 'r')
NameError: global name 'filename' is not defined

Here is my code:

```
  # handle submit button
def submit(self, event):
    file = open(filename.GetValue(), 'r')
    contents.SetValue(file.read())
    file.close()

def createForm(self):

    # establish the wxPython App 
    app = wx.App()

    # establish the wxPython frame
    win = wx.Frame(None,title="Closes Neighbor", size = (610,535))

    # define the screen widgets

    # text controls
    filename = wx.TextCtrl(win, pos = (100, 50), size = (210, 25))
    latitude = wx.TextCtrl(win, pos = (100, 80), size = (210, 25))
    longitude = wx.TextCtrl(win, pos = (100, 110), size = (210, 25))
    description = wx.TextCtrl(win, pos = (100, 140), size = (210, 25))
    answer = wx.TextCtrl(win, pos = (100, 250), size = (400, 50),
                         style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.HSCROLL)
    answer.SetEditable(False)
    messages = wx.TextCtrl(win, pos = (100, 350), size = (400, 50),
                         style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.HSCROLL)
    messages.SetEditable(False)

    # static labels
    lblTitle = wx.StaticText (win, pos = (200, 25), size = (210,25),
                                label = "Closest Neighbor", style = wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
    lblFilename = wx.StaticText (win, pos = (10, 50), size = (210,25),
                                label = "Filename:")
    lblLatitude = wx.StaticText (win, pos = (10, 80), size = (210,25),
                                label = "Latitude:")
    lblLongitude = wx.StaticText (win, pos = (10, 110), size = (210,25),
                                label = "Longitude:")
    lblDescription = wx.StaticText (win, pos = (10, 140), size = (210,25),
                                label = "Description:")
    lblAnswer = wx.StaticText (win, pos = (10, 250), size = (210,25),
                                label = "Answer:")
    lblMessages = wx.StaticText (win, pos = (10, 350), size = (210,25),
                                label = "Messages:")

    # buttons
    submitButton = wx.Button(win, label='Find the Closest Point',
                           pos = (100, 180), size = (180, 25))
    submitButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.submit)

    # get the ball roling
    win.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Change all references to `filename` to `self.filename`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, the easiest way to achieve what you want is to change the reference to `self.filename` but in answer to the question asked, yes you can.
Use the `lambda` function.

```
import wx

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args)
        Button = wx.Button(self, -1, "Click me")
        Button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: self.OnButton(event, flag1="Parameter", flag2="Something else"))
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(Button,1,0,0)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.Show()

    def OnButton(self, event, flag1, flag2):
        print ("The Button was pressed")
        print ("Flag1 was set to ", flag1)
        print ("Flag2 was set to ", flag2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    myframe = TestFrame(None, -1, "Button Test")
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]